# How to fix login bug in Stack Overflow app on iPhones?

Tags: bug, login, stack-overflow-app

I have a normal account and usually log in with Email and Password using the Chrome browser.

The login on my browser works perfect, but now I installed the Stack Overflow iPhone app on my iPhone 5s.

I got the following error message in the app:

### Login

**More** > ***Log in or sign up***

[On this login screen](https://image.ibb.co/m0gbAn/AppLogin.jpg), I got this error:

> ## Request failed
>
> ### Bad password

[image: Standard login error message]

### OpenID Login

***More** > **Log in or sign up** > **more login options**

[On this login screen](https://ibb.co/dxjGbS), I got this error:

> The email or password is incorrect.

[image: Open ID Login Error]

## What I'm trying to solve with this problem:

- Typing my email and password over and over again
- Changing my password with browser and smartphone
- Searching google
- Searching Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

## I found a solution

I had to logout one time in my browser.

So I clicked on Users and add `/logout` in the URL following by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now you are on the "hidden logout-screen". Click on the checkbox "log out on all devices" and click the **Log Out** button.

Here comes a screenshot:

[image: log out on all devices]

And as long as I'm not logged in again, the app login works.

After this initial app login, it works also if I'm logged in with my browser too.

I think it is a bug.